Validation models separated from views with Flask
I have the following project structure:
.
├── pyproject.toml
└── simpleproj
    ├── myapp
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── run.py

It is a simplification of a bigger project in Flask that implements an API interacting with Mongo. This is the content of the files in the simplified project.
simpleproj/run.py:
from simpleproj.myapp import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)


simpleproj/myapp/__init__.py:
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    from simpleproj.myapp.views import core_bp
    app.register_blueprint(core_bp)

    return app


simpleproj/myapp/views.py:
from flask import Blueprint, request
from flask_restx import Api, Resource, fields


core_bp = Blueprint("core", __name__)

api = Api(
    app=core_bp,
    version="1.0",
    title="Simple API",
    description="My simple API",
)
ns = api.namespace("api/v1/", description="Version 1 of the api")


wildcard = fields.Wildcard(
    fields.Nested(
        api.model(
            "Collection Data",
            {
                "modified": fields.DateTime,
                "version": fields.String,
            },
        )
    )
)
my_data = api.model(
    "My Data",
    {
        "name": fields.String(required=True),
        "collection": fields.Nested(
            api.model(
                "Collection Names",
                {
                    "*": wildcard,
                },
            )
        ),
    },
)


@ns.route("/processdata", methods=["POST"])
class Data(Resource):
    @api.expect(my_data, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()
        processed_data = data
        processed_data["new_field"] = "New field"
        return processed_data


In my real project views.py is very large and I thought it could be a good idea to move the validation models (i.e., api.model(...) used in api.expect and api.marshal_with) to another file called validation.py. However, I do not know how to achieve this the correct way.
I have tried modifying views.py and validation.py in the following way:
simpleproj/myapp/views.py:
from flask import Blueprint, request
from flask_restx import Api, Resource, Model
from simpleproj.myapp.validation import register_validation_models


core_bp = Blueprint("core", __name__)

api = Api(
    app=core_bp,
    version="1.0",
    title="Simple API",
    description="My simple API",
)
ns = api.namespace("api/v1/", description="Version 1 of the api")

register_validation_models(api)


@ns.route("/processdata", methods=["POST"])
class Data(Resource):
    @api.expect(Model("My Data"), validate=True)
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()
        processed_data = data
        processed_data["new_field"] = "New field"
        return processed_data


simpleproj/myapp/validation.py:
from flask_restx import fields, Model

wildcard = fields.Wildcard(fields.Nested(Model("Collection Data")))

models = {
    "Collection Data": {
        "modified": fields.DateTime,
        "version": fields.String,
    },
    "Collection Names": {"*": wildcard},
    "My Data": {
        "name": fields.String(required=True),
        "collection": fields.Nested(Model("Collection Names")),
    },
}


def register_validation_models(api):
    for model_name, model_data in models.items():
        api.models[model_name] = Model(model_name, model_data)


It works well, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it as it does not feel easy to read the validation.py models dict. I tried to import api variable from validation.py to be able to do my_data_model = api.model() and then import my_data_model from views.py. However, I cannot do this because it will cause a CircularImport error.
I will like to solve the following questions:

Is this project structure okey?
Does it makes sense to have the models for validation and marshalling in a separate file (i.e., validation.py in my case)? should I focus on separating views.py in different files with different Blueprints instead?


Have a look at this boilerplate https://github.com/Ikigaisys/Flask-restx-Boilerplate
